# Optimizing Hexadecimal To Ascii Function in C++

Tags: c++, function, hex, ascii

This is a function in c++ that takes a HEX string and converts it to its equivalent ASCII character.

```
string HEX2STR (string str)
{
    string tmp;
    const char *c = str.c_str();
    unsigned int x;
    while(*c != 0) {
        sscanf(c, "%2X", &x);
        tmp += x;
        c += 2;
    }
    return tmp;
```

If you input the following string:

```
537461636b6f766572666c6f77206973207468652062657374212121
```

The output will be:

```
Stackoverflow is the best!!!
```

Say I were to input 1,000,000 unique HEX strings into this function, it takes awhile to compute.

Is there a more efficient way to complete this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course. Look up two characters at a time:

```
unsigned char val(char c)
{
    if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') { return c      - '0'; }
    if ('a' <= c && c <= 'f') { return c + 10 - 'a'; }
    if ('A' <= c && c <= 'F') { return c + 10 - 'A'; }
    throw "Eeek";
}

std::string decode(std::string const & s)
{
    if (s.size() % 2) != 0) { throw "Eeek"; }

    std::string result;
    result.reserve(s.size() / 2);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < s.size() / 2; ++i)
    {
        unsigned char n = val(s[2 * i]) * 16 + val(s[2 * i + 1]);
        result += n;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.
Much appreciated Kerrek SB and Mark Ransom!

Answer (score 2):

Just since I wrote it anyway, this should be fairly efficient :)

```
const char lookup[32] =
     {0,10,11,12,13,14,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,0,0,0,0,0};

std::string HEX2STR(std::string str)
{
  std::string out;
  out.reserve(str.size()/2);

  const char* tmp = str.c_str();

  unsigned char ch, last = 1;
  while(*tmp)
  {
    ch <<= 4;
    ch |= lookup[*tmp&0x1f];
    if(last ^= 1) 
      out += ch;
    tmp++;
  }
  return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use sscanf.  It's a very general flexible function, which means its slow to allow all those usecases.  Instead, walk the string and convert each character yourself, much faster.

Answer (score 0):

This routine takes a string with (what I call) hexwords, often used in embedded ECUs, for example "31 01 7F 33 38 33 37 30 35 31 30 30 20 20 49" and transforms it in readable ASCII where possible.
Transforms by taking care of the discontuinity in the ASCII table (0-9: 48-57, A-F:65 - 70);

```
    int i,j, len=strlen(stringWithHexWords);
    char ascii_buffer[250];
    char c1, c2, r;

    i=0;
    j=0;

    while (i<len) {

        c1 = stringWithHexWords[i];
        c2 = stringWithHexWords[i+1];

        if ((int)c1!=32) {  // if space found, skip next section and bump index only once                                       
        // skip scary ASCII codes                                       
           if (32<(int)c1 && 127>(int)c1 && 32<(int)c2 && 127>(int)c2)  { 
//

           // transform by taking first hexdigit * 16 and add second hexdigit
           // both with correct offset


            r = (char) ((16*(int)c1+((int)c2<64?((int)c2-48):((int)c2-55)))); 


            if (31<(int)r && 127>(int)r) 
                      ascii_buffer[j++] = r;   // check result for readability      
           }
          i++;  // bump index 
     }   

    i++;  // bump index once more for next hexdigit
}

ascii_bufferCurrentLength = j;
return true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The hexToString() function will convert hex string to ASCII readable string

```
string hexToString(string str){
    std::stringstream HexString;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        char a = str.at(i++);
        char b = str.at(i);
        int x = hexCharToInt(a);
        int y = hexCharToInt(b);
        HexString << (char)((16*x)+y);
    }
    return HexString.str();
}

int hexCharToInt(char a){
    if(a>='0' && a<='9')
        return(a-48);
    else if(a>='A' && a<='Z')
        return(a-55);
    else
        return(a-87);
}
```